# How to group columns when the value repeats in sql

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, accessdatasource

I connected my Access DB to an Excel file and executed a few simple SQL queries and I want to do something that I don't know if it is possible.

I want to group values in columns when the values repeat.

For example, here is a simple query results:

`ID | Name | Color
 1    John    Red
 1    John    Yellow
 2    Bill    Red
 2    Bill    Blue
 2    Bill    Black`

I would like the results to be presented in that way:

`ID | Name | Color
 1    John    Red
              Yellow
 2    Bill    Red
              Blue
              Black`

Is that possible?

Appreciate your answers!

Thanks.

Comment: Using sql alone, it is not possible. What do you need it for?

Comment: I need it for convenient data appearance, because the results of my query are much bigger than that simple query.

Comment: @ImranAli All the tags are relevant: Using Excel to connect my Access data source and executing SQL query.

Comment: @GiladK If you are generating a report in MS Access it is possible to produce the way you want it. You just need to follow the Access Report Wizard and group your data on the Name column

Comment: @ImranAli I can't create the report - it fails everytime because of too many selected fields which I must have them all.

Comment: @GiladK Are you familiar with using VBA? it would be simple to move down columns  `ID` and `Name` and if the value is equal to the value above then clear the cell. This method is easier once you have created the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be a result of a SQL query, the query will display the values in 'ID' and 'Name' fields associated with 'Color' field, if they exist. moreover, in the query result there will be nothing associating *Blue* to *Bill* rather than *Jhon*.

If your goal is to display in Excel, you can have code run through Cols ID and NAME, bottom to top, and delete cells whom values equal to the cell above.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..Nothing is Impossible..

```
create table tbl_table
(Id int,
Name varchar(32),
Color varchar(16)
)
go

insert into tbl_table
values(1,'John','Red');
insert into tbl_table
values(1,'John','Yellow');
insert into tbl_table
values(2,'Bill','Red');
insert into tbl_table
values(2,'Bill','Blue');
insert into tbl_table
values(2,'Bill','Black');
go

select a.id,case when a.Id=b.Id and a.rowid<>b.rowid then NULL else a.Name end,a.Color
from
(
select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Order by Id asc ) rowid,* from tbl_table
) a
left join
(
select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Order by Id asc ) rowid,* from tbl_table
) b
on a.rowid-1=b.rowid
```

Thanks

Comment: This query doesn't work for me. I'm trying to execute the query in the SQL queries editor in Access.

Comment: Which version do you use..??

Comment: I'm using Access 2013

Comment: Can we use team viewer..?

Comment: Please format your code. `ROW_NUMBER ()` is for SQL Server, Access doesn't have this.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tbl_table
(Id int,
Name varchar(32),
Color varchar(16)
)
go

insert into tbl_table
values(1,'John','Red');
insert into tbl_table
values(1,'John','Yellow');
insert into tbl_table
values(2,'Bill','Red');
insert into tbl_table
values(2,'Bill','Blue');
insert into tbl_table
values(2,'Bill','Black');
go

select a.id,case when a.Id=b.Id and a.rowid<>b.rowid then NULL else a.Name end,a.Color
from
(
select DCount("[ID]","[tbl_table]","[ID]<=" & [ID]) rowid,* from tbl_table
) a
left join
(
select DCount("[ID]","[tbl_table]","[ID]<=" & [ID]) rowid,* from tbl_table
) b
on a.rowid-1=b.rowid
```

Try This

Comment: @Andre Hi, It doesn't work for some reason. I get error message: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'case when a.Id=b.Id and a.rowid<>b.rowid then NULL else a.Name end'." and it marks the word "when" right after I click on OK.

Comment: @GiladK: I didn't write this code, I just formatted it. :) You need to use IIf() instead of Case When.

Comment: I replaced the case when with IIf() and now error indicates on DCount. I receive the same error as I got with the 'case when', with 'DCount' now..